# "com_error: (-2147417851, 'The server threw an exception.', None, None)"

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pywin32

I need to copy data from three excel files & paste into three different excel files.

```
Error:
     ('F', 'C:\\Users\\jmp655972\\Desktop\\SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT\\Folder Creation               Format\\Base Vehicle Laden\\Steady State\\Continous Test Data\\LH Turn\\test_1.csv')
Pass
('F', 'C:\\Users\\jmp655972\\Desktop\\SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT\\Folder Creation Format\\Base Vehicle Laden\\Steady State\\Continous Test Data\\LH Turn\\test_2.csv')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmp655972\Desktop\Handling_Analysis_Software\main.py", line 120, in <module>
    filescheck(fileCount)
  File "C:\Users\jmp655972\Desktop\Handling_Analysis_Software\main.py", line 115, in filescheck
    readFilesAndCopyData(excelObj,"roll","1",csvfile)
  File "C:\Users\jmp655972\Desktop\Handling_Analysis_Software\main.py", line 62, in readFilesAndCopyData
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filetoOpen)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x6.py", line 34940, in Open
    , Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
com_error: (-2147417851, 'The server threw an exception.', None, None

def openExcel():
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = 1
return excel;



def readFilesAndCopyData(excel,testtype,vehicletype,filetoOpen):
    currworkingdirectory = os.getcwd()
    print ("F",filetoOpen)
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filetoOpen)
    worksheets = workbook.Worksheets(1)
    if testtype == "roll":
        if vehicletype == "1":
            print ("Pass")
            worksheets.Range("E:E,H:H,I:I").Select()
            worksheets.Range("E:E,H:H,I:I").Copy()
        else:
            worksheets.Range("L:L,O:O,P:P").Select()
            worksheets.Range("L:L,O:O,P:P").Copy()
    elif testtype == "slip":
        if vehicletype == "1":
            worksheets.Range("E:E,G:G").Select()
            worksheets.Range("E:E,G:G").Copy()
        else:
            worksheets.Range("E:E,G:G").Select()
            worksheets.Range("E:E,G:G").Copy()
    else:
        print("No Test Data Found")

    workbook.Close
    pasteCopiedData(excel)
    counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when was trying to copy a column from one sheet to another sheet in the same workbook. But while doing so I had 2 other workbooks opened. I thought server error might mean some sort of performance issue. So I tried to first close the other two workbooks (which were not required) and then do the copy function.

I think this resolves the issue since I have not got the error again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error message while trying to automate Excel work. Specifically, a line of code which was supposed to open an Excel file threw this error. The reason seemed to be the fact the file path (directory + file name) was way too long. The error was gone when I renamed folders and file name to give them shorter name.